# "Table doesn't exist in engine" for innoDB tables after recovery attempt

Tags: mysql, innodb

I'm trying to restore a database from an old server, the person in charge lost their data backups, and only mysql folder remains. The database uses both MyISAM and InnoDB engines. For the InnoDB tables, if I check inside their folders I don't see individual .ibd files. So it seems to me all the data is stored in ibdata1.

What I've tried:

1. Install the same Mysql version on the new server
2. Copy /data folder from the old server to the new server
3. Set innodb-log-file-size in my .cnf to match the size of ib_logfile0
4. Start mysql

After MySQL is started, I can select all the tables created using MyISAM engine but for innoDB tables I get an error saying `Table doesn't exist in engine`. The same message also happens when I use mysqlcheck to try and repair the table, all db commands to the table also resulted in the same error message.

Is there anything specific I'm missing?